# How to prevent jQuery-ui from adding classes to my UL?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using jQuery-ui to add a datepicker to a Wordpress site. I am having this strange problem where it is adding classes to a UL that is totally unrelated to the datepicker.

Here is the HTML for the page menu, as it looks WITHOUT jQuery-ui being loaded and a datepicker being initiated:

```
<ul id="menu-airhawk" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-780" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-780"><a href="http://airhawkdrones.ca/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-774" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-774"><a href="http://airhawkdrones.ca/about-our-drones/">Drones</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-783" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-783"><a href="http://airhawkdrones.ca/gopro/">GoPro</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-777" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-777"><a href="#">Media</a>
```

Here is the same menu when jQUery-UI is loaded and a datepicker has been initiated  somewhere on the page.

```
<ul id="menu-airhawk-1" class="menu ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-front ui-menu-item" role="menuitem" aria-hidden="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-780 ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><a href="http://airhawkdrones.ca/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-774 ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><a href="http://airhawkdrones.ca/about-our-drones/">Drones</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-783 ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-4" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><a href="http://airhawkdrones.ca/gopro/">GoPro</a></li>
```

As you can see here, the classes ui-menu, ui-widget and a few other jQUery UI classes are being added.

Here is the code I am using to assign the datepicker component to an element:

```
start_date.datepicker({
            minDate: '+1d',
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {

                var end_date = jQuery(this).datepicker("getDate");
                end_date.setDate(end_date.getDate() + 1);
                jQuery( "#end_date" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", end_date );
              }
        });
```

How can I prevent jQUery UI from adding these classes to the totally unrelated menu?

If there is any other code or information I can add to help answer this, just let me know.

Comment: Do you have another plugin that instruments the `<ul>` as a menu? Perhaps you have code like `$('.menu').menu()` for that plugin, but when you include the jQuery UI library, `.menu()` is overridden to be the jQuery UI menu plugin.

Comment: Nothing in my plug-in is like this. Not sure if the theme has something. I did find sort of a fix. I remembered when I did the jQuery downloade, I selected pretty much everything. I went back and only chose what was needed for the datepicker and it solved the issue.

Comment: That's the solution I was going to suggest, and since it works, I'm pretty sure there's another plugin defining a `.menu()` method. Your "sort of" fix is really the correct way to fix this. You could post it as an answer, but you should list the theme you are using.

Comment: I'm not finding anything like .menu() in the theme JS. Is there another way to see if an element is being attached to a plugin?

Comment: When an element is instrumented by a plugin, the plugin attaches event handlers to the element. I think some browsers allow you to see that, but I'm not sure what that will tell you. You could at least check if a `.menu()` function has been attached to the jQuery object prototype.

Comment: I think you just went over my head. I looked around the Google developer tools, but found nothing. Anyway, it's not that important.I found a work around and will post it as an answer. Thanks